# Tao Analysis I, exercise 5.2.2.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I have proved the following statement and would like to know if my proof seems correct.

Let ε > 0. Show that if $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are eventually
ε-close, then $(a_n)$ is bounded iff $(b_n)$ is bounded.

[see this snapshot from the text itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSb2d.png)

Proof:
Since $a_n$ and $b_n$ are ε-close, we know that for all $ε > 0$ there exists a natural number $N$, such that $$|a_n - b_n| \le ε,$$ $$ n\ge N $$
Since $b_n$ is bounded, $|b_n|<=M_1$ for some natural number $M_1$.
Set $ε = 1$. Then there exist a natural number $N$ such that $$|a_n - b_n| \le 1,$$ $$ n\ge N $$ Applying the reverse triangle inequality:
$$ |a_n| - |b_n| \le |a_n - b_n| \le 1$$ thus: $$ |a_n| \le 1 + |b_n| $$ For $ n < N $, $ (a_n)$ is a sequence of finite elements and thus bounded (it is assumed this fact does not need to be proved), say by the natural number $M_2$. For $ n \ge N, |a_n| \le  1 + M_1$  (since $b_n$ is bounded).

Set $M_3 =  max(M_2, 1 + M_1)$. Then for all $n$, $|a_n| \le M_3$.

Thus $(a_n)$ is bounded, and the proof is completed.

Comment: Yes, this looks fine.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: Fine... You could also say that  $n>N\implies |a_n|\le |a_n-b_n|+|b_n|\le \varepsilon +M_1$, and therefore    $\forall n\, (|a_n|\le M^*) $ where $M^*=\max (\{M_1+\varepsilon\}\cup \{|a_n|:n\le N\}).$

Comment: I don't think it's correct to set $\varepsilon=1$. You are only given an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ and you need to work with that. Since we are talking about $\varepsilon$-close, there is no "for all" in the definition. If you were working with equivalent sequences, then you could do that. Small detail, but still